# Nagios Output Formatting

Tags: bash, awk, sed, snmp, nagios

Short version:

Is there a better way of writing the check below?

```
./check_snmp -H x.x.x.x -o oidstring -C public | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/.$/.&/' | sed -e 's/$/ KB/'
```

Long version:

I have a Nagios service check that outputs a three digit number:

```
./check_snmp -H x.x.x.x -o oidstring -C public

SNMP OK - 711 | iso.oidstring=711
```

This is what I have done to format it to my liking and to give an accurate value:

```
./check_snmp -H x.x.x.x -o oidstring -C public | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/.$/.&/' | sed -e 's/$/ KB/'

71.1 KB
```

The output is perfect and I can run the command within the CentOS environment without issue, but when attempting to implement the check within Nagios, the service does not return and value and instead I get (No output on stdout).

Strangely, I can even perform a service test check within Nagios successfully, but the page that displays the host and service values is the one that gives the (No output on stdout).

I think Nagios doesn't like the way I'm attempting to format my output, at least on the web side of things.

Is there a 'neater' way of writing the check above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is what you're asking about, but you can do without the sed statements and change the awk to `awk '{print ($4 / 10) " KB"}'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using either a single sed (uses the dash as anchor):

```
 ... | sed 's/^.*- \([0-9]*\)\([0-9]\) .*$/\1.\2 KB/'
```

or a single awk:

```
... | awk '{printf "%s KB\n", $4/10}'
```

Comment: Both examples work great, thanks! FTR, the example above by @jas works great too. Thanks for helping me clean up my ugly service check.

Answer (score 0):

My Icinga shows me a null.

`$USER1$/check_snmp -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C SNMP -o .1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.5.0 $ARG1$ | awk '{printf "%s V\n", $4/10}'`

When I do this manually I have the correct Output: 80.2V